# android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView dialog

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to make a high score list, accessible from my main menu. I am trying to achieve this by using dialog. My dialog class:

```
public class CustonDialog extends Dialog {
    private LinearLayout layout;
    private Context mContext;

    public CustonDialog(Context context) {
        super(context, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_highscore);
        setCancelable(false);
        mContext = context;

        Button buttonClose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_close);
        buttonClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dismiss();
            }
        });

    }
    public void addKeyValuePair(String key, String value) {
      /* View row_key = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row_key,layout,false);
        TextView textView_key = (TextView) row_key.findViewById(R.id.row_textView_key);
        View row_value = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row_value,layout,false);
        TextView textView_value = (TextView) row_value.findViewById(R.id.row_textView_value);
*/
     // TextView textView_key = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.row_textView_value);
        TextView textView_key = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row_key,layout,false);
        TextView textView_value = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row_value,layout,false);

        textView_key.setText(key);
        textView_value.setText(value);

        layout.addView(textView_key);
        layout.addView(textView_value);
    }
}
```

With xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button_close"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

and:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="dummy_text"
        android:id="@+id/row_textView_key"
        android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20sp">
    <include layout="@layout/row_value"/>
</TextView>
```

and:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="dummy_value"
    android:id="@+id/row_textView_value"
    android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
    android:textSize="30sp">
<include layout="@layout/row_key"/>
</TextView>
```

When I run the code, it casts an exception "android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView, when reaching the first line of the void addKeyValuePair. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: post the stacktrace

Comment: I have just added it.

Answer (score 0):

**Instead of**

```
TextView textView_key = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row_key,layout,false);
    TextView textView_value = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row_value,layout,false);
```

write `TextView textView_key = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.row_textView_value)`

it seems that `R.layout.row_key` is a linear layout and deffintly it connot be cast to textView just bind the variable with the actual text view which is `row_textView_value` like what you have did with the button above
and be aware the textviews must be in the same layout which you added in setContentView otherwise you have to include the layouts in XML like typing 
 `<include />` tag

```
<include layout="@layout/row_key"/>
```

**after reading the updated question here is the update 2**

```
<Button
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/button_close"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:textStyle="bold" />
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
        android:orientation="vertical">
 <include layout="@layout/row_value"/>
 <include layout="@layout/row_key"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

remove the include from other xml files

Comment: Now  I get this:  
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                            at com.example.sofie.galgeleg.CustonDialog.addKeyValuePair(CustonDialog.java:43)
                                                                            at com.example.sofie.galgeleg.MainMenu.onClick(MainMenu.java:67)

Comment: have you added the textViews in same layout ?

Comment: I have separate xml files for row_key and row_value

Comment: I tried removing the LinearLayout initiation in row_key and row_value. Now I get this:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                              at com.example.sofie.galgeleg.CustonDialog.addKeyValuePair(CustonDialog.java:50)
                                                                              at com.example.sofie.galgeleg.MainMenu.onClick(MainMenu.java:67)

Comment: if you have it in separate xml then you have to include the other XML files

Comment: I made an include statement in both row_key and row_value. I get this exception:


java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                     at com.example.sofie.galgeleg.CustonDialog.addKeyValuePair(CustonDialog.java:50)
                                                     at com.example.sofie.galgeleg.MainMenu.onClick(MainMenu.java:67)

Comment: can you update the question with full code you have update ?

Answer (score 0):

You layouts `R.layout.row_key` and `R.layout.row_value` having `LinearLayout` as root container. This is why you are getting this Exception.

> android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView dialogs

**Solution**
1. Make your both layout contain only `TextView` only as .

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="dummy_value"
        android:id="@+id/row_textView_value"
        android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
        android:textSize="30sp">
    </TextView>
```

2. When inflating the layout you can get into a View .

   ```
   View row_key=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row_key,null);
   TextView textView_key = (TextView)row_key.findViewById(R.id.textView1) ;
   View row_value=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row_value,null);
   TextView textView_value=(TextView)row_value.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
   ```

Comment: To 2.
when I write "textView textView_key" It gives me an error that says it's already defined in the scope

When I write "row_key.findViewById();"   it says it cannot resolve row_key. The same goes for row_value

Comment: This can be some typo error of mine . Just use ids as per your layout . I have only given you an example . have you tried first solution which is only xml changes

Comment: Now I get this exception:

 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.LinearLayout.addView(android.view.View)' on a null object reference
                                                                              at com.example.sofie.galgeleg.CustonDialog.addKeyValuePair(CustonDialog.java:53)
                                                                              at com.example.sofie.galgeleg.MainMenu.onClick(MainMenu.java:67)

Comment: Just UNDO your code til old one and use the first solution.

Comment: Where did you initilize `private LinearLayout layout;` i do not see in your code .

Comment: The above solution should work . Debug your code . And use above solution .